# set custom price in layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, price, layered-navigation

I have put my custom logic for change price in product listing page using below event

```
catalog_product_collection_load_after
```

This event set successfully set custom price in product listing page but it display wrong price in layered navigation .

so my question is How to set custom price in `layered navigation` ?

Any help or guidance will be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Is it displaying wrong price in navigation, or no price? Can I see your logic? I suspect the 'used in layered navigation' property is not being set.

Comment: it display product orignal price @TimHallman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Layered navigation uses prices from the table `catalog_product_index_price`

This table is created and maintained up to date by Magento built in price indexing mechanism.

So you can modify the price on the event `catalog_product_save_before`, modified price will be saved and the core will do all the magic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer But I want to change price of layered navigation on fly due to some my custom condition. @Amasty

Comment: Then you need to alter the table values on the fly for corresponding products as well.

Comment: Hi @KeyurShah, have you got the answer?

Comment: unfortunately not ! :) @Gmb